# How to resolve unexpected token error with grep, regex, and PHP?

Tags: php, regex, bash, grep, token

I know REGEX well enough but am stuck on this one.  I am using PHP 5.4 to shell_exec() a grep statement with REGEX inside it to capture the SKU in a text file.  In php I don't see an error but the grep doesn't work.

The goal is to capture the SKU in this text:

```
{'Product_Product_SKU':               'DOP36M94DPM'},
```

PHP Code:

```
$cmdSKU1 = 'grep -Po \'(?<=\{\'Product_Product_SKU\':\s{15}\').+?(?=\'\}\,)\' '.$FileName;
$chkSKU1 = trim(shell_exec($cmdSKU1));
```

Furthermore, when I look at the $cmdSKU1 variable in the debugger tool of the IDE I am using it's value is this as one line:

```
grep -Po '(?<=\{'Product_Product_SKU':\s{15}').+?(?='\}\,)' /opt/web/default/RetailerParsing/RetailerDownload/MDD30TMSTH__20220113091043.htm
```

Furthermore some more, when I paste it into the Ubuntu console it gives me the error:

```
-bash: syntax eror near unexpected token `)'
```

Even if I go back and escape the exposed single quotes.  Infact, I escaped everything [^A-Za-z0-9] just to make sure! No beans.

Lastly, if I try to double escape the single quotes within the REGEX in the PHP IDE I get a red squiggly underline error under the words *Produce_Product_SKU*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not escaping the shell command correctly. Instead of doing it manually, you should use ​`escapeshellarg`:

```php
$cmdSKU1 = join(" ", array_map( 'escapeshellarg', array(
   ​"grep",
   ​"-Po",
   ​"(?<={'Product_Product_SKU':\s{15}').+?(?='},)",
   ​$FileName
)));
$chkSKU1 = trim(shell_exec($cmdSKU1));
```

That said, why not directly use `preg_match` and save a call to a non POSIX external command?

```php
$string = "{'Product_Product_SKU':               'DOP36M94DPM'},";

preg_match("/{'Product_Product_SKU':\s{15}'([^']+)'}/", $string, $matches);
```

```php
var_dump($matches[1]);
string(11) "DOP36M94DPM"
```

Of course you'll have to read the file inside php, but it may be worth the extra code.

Comment: That's the ticket!  Thanks, Fravadona.  I appreciate the clear insightful answer - and fast.  Learned something very usefull to me which I can incorporate into my web scraping efforts.  Our norm is to grep the file many times extracting prices and such.  Using a 'read file then preg_match' method may well be less resource intensive.  Something I should investigate.  Big thanks on that.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need regex at all here, and certainly not a shell_exec. Just split on `'` and take the 4th (0-indexed) value out of the resulting array:

```
$str = "{'Product_Product_SKU':               'DOP36M94DPM'},";
$sku = explode("'", $str)[3];
var_dump($sku);
```

Yields:

```
string(11) "DOP36M94DPM"
```

Also note PHP 5.4 was end-of-lifed over 6 years ago. You really should update.

Comment: From what I understood of the question, the pattern is to be extracted from a file

Comment: The _pattern_? No, the pattern is clearly hard-coded. I think you mean the _text to search_ is coming from a file. Without knowing what else is in that file, it's hard to provide more detail than to just dump the example string in a variable.

Comment: Thanks Alex, but I am reading from numerous text files searching for SKUs.  Appreciate it, though.